# Which cryptocurrency exchange provides a trailing stop limit orders?

Tags: exchanges

There so many exchanges as of today (2017), but they all seem to only provide a basic stop limit order, but are there any exchanges that provide a trailing stop limit order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitfinex has trailing stop. 123

Answer (score 2):

Bitfinex has trailing stop, but not trailing stop limit order. Stop loss orders has the potential risk of selling your coins at a very low price in case of sudden short term market crashes.

I am still looking for a cryptocurrency exchange platform that provides a trailing stop limit order, if anyone knows one.

Answer (score 1):

Kraken no longer offers this feature: https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/203325793-Stop-Loss-Orders

Answer (score 0):

other exchanges use trailing stop are Bitstamp and kraken (tier3 need).
Bitstamp though support only BTC, XRP, ETH, LTC and BCH. Kraken much more but not as many as other exchanges